# Add new gems to an existing image and create a new Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-build

I'm trying to add new gems to an existing Docker image which doesn't have a Dockerfile. Below is what I have tried:

```
 - logged into the `bash` Docker image 
 - gem install <new dependency>
```

How do I create a new image after the above steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `docker commit` command. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/).

Comment: Thanks this worked for me `docker commit --change='CMD [gem install aws-sdk]' 1jsrgi7748 myimage:v2`

Comment: The `—change` parameter expects Dockerfile commands. “gem” is not a Dockerfile command. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#options), under Extended Description. For what you are wanting to do, you need to run the “gem” command ni a running container. `sudo docker exec -it [container name] bash` - that will give you an interactive bash session. From there you can run your Ruby command.